# Import from .csv to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm new in PostgreSQL. Have a working MySQL query making import from .csv:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/d/docs/DB.csv'
INTO TABLE calculations.pricing FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

How can I fix it working with Postgre. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) command is your friend.